# How do I set up a click-to-chat link for Smooch (web messenger)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, smooch

I'm moving from PureChat to Smooch. I used to have a link on my WordPress site that, when clicked, would open a PureChat widget. It looked like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" class="purechat-button-expand">Text</a>
```

Now I'd like to achieve the same thing with the Smooch web messenger:

1. User clicks links
2. Smooch chat widget opens

... can you help me figure it out?

Comment: can you please send me a your website url?So I can get idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already ran `Smooch.init({...})` before and properly initialized the Web Messenger, you can then simply have a link like this :

`<a href="javascript:Smooch.open()">Text</a>`

You can find more information about what you can do with the library on the [Github repo](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-js#open)

Answer (score 1):

You can call chat Button on link click,

```
    $(function () {


    $(document).on("click", "#anchorId", function () {
        $("#sk-messenger-button").click();
    });
});
```

`sk-messenger-button` button id on website of https://smooch.io/.

**In other-way,**

```
$("#sk-messenger-button").click();
```